# Java : How do I group all java Dates in their corresponding week?

Tags: java, date

**Problem:**

I have a large list of dates and I need to arrange them all by week.

**Question:**
How do I group dates by the **week of the year** that they are in?

**Example Data Set**

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/01/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/02/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/03/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/04/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/05/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/06/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/07/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/08/2015")
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat.parse("04/09/2015")
```

**Desired Output**

```
HashMap<Date, Date> hashMap = groupByWeek(ArrayList<Date> dates);

printWeeklyGroupedDates();

Week 1:
04/01/2015
04/02/2015
04/03/2015
04/04/2015
04/05/2015
04/06/2015
04/07/2015
Week 2:
04/08/2015
04/09/2015
```

What I've Tried

```
public Date getWhichYearlyWeek(Date date){

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  cal.get(Calendear.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

  //Need to return this as 'Date' but indicate which week this is for the TreeMap functionality below          

  return cal.getTime();
}


public TreeMap<Date, ArrayList<Date>> getWeeklyMappedDates(ArrayList<Date> dateArray){

  TreeMap<Date, ArrayList<Date>> treeMap = new TreeMap<Date, ArrayList<Date>>

  for(Date i : dateArray){

    Date date = getWhichYearlyWeek(date);

    if(!treeMap.containsKey(date))
      treeMap.get(date).add(date);
    else
      treeMap.put(date, new ArrayList<Date>());
  }

  return treeMap;
}
```

Comment: It's quite simple if you use GregorianCalendar, have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: Convert the Date object to Calendar and use WEEK_OF_YEAR to group dates.

Comment: You can use Calendar.getWeekYear: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getWeekYear()

Comment: Well one important question is whether the same week across different years should be grouped together or not? If so, then the answers here are not sufficient I would say.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Some of the answers show you how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply sort the `List` of `Date`s using a custom `Comparator`.  The following example sorts the date's by week of year and then by date, don't know if you want the second part, but it's a nice demonstration...

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(25);
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/01/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/02/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/03/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/04/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/05/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/06/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/07/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/08/2015"));
            dates.add(sdf.parse("04/09/2015"));

            int week = 0;
            int woy = -1;
            Collections.sort(dates, new WeekComparator());
            for (Date date : dates) {
                if (woy != getWeekOfYear(date)) {
                    woy = getWeekOfYear(date);
                    week++;
                    System.out.println("Week " + week + ":");
                }
                System.out.println(date);
            }

        } catch (ParseException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class WeekComparator implements Comparator<Date> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
            int result = getWeekOfYear(o1) - getWeekOfYear(o2);
            if (result == 0) {
                result = o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    protected static int getWeekOfYear(Date date) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        return cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    }

}
```

Which outputs

```
Week 1:
Wed Apr 01 00:00:00 EST 2015
Thu Apr 02 00:00:00 EST 2015
Fri Apr 03 00:00:00 EST 2015
Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 EST 2015
Week 2:
Sun Apr 05 00:00:00 EST 2015
Mon Apr 06 00:00:00 EST 2015
Tue Apr 07 00:00:00 EST 2015
Wed Apr 08 00:00:00 EST 2015
Thu Apr 09 00:00:00 EST 2015
```

## Java 8 Time API

And just because I need the practice...

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

        List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>(25);
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/01/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/02/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/03/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/04/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/05/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/06/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/07/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/08/2015", dtf));
        dates.add(LocalDate.parse("04/09/2015", dtf));

        int week = 0;
        int woy = -1;
        Collections.sort(dates, new WeekComparator());
        for (LocalDate date : dates) {
            if (woy != getWeekOfYear(date)) {
                woy = getWeekOfYear(date);
                week++;
                System.out.println("Week " + week + ":");
            }
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }

    public static class WeekComparator implements Comparator<LocalDate> {

        @Override
        public int compare(LocalDate o1, LocalDate o2) {
            int result = getWeekOfYear(o1) - getWeekOfYear(o2);
            if (result == 0) {
                result = o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    protected static int getWeekOfYear(LocalDate date) {
        WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
        return date.get(wf.weekOfYear());
    }

}
```

Which outputs

```
Week 1:
2015-04-01
2015-04-02
2015-04-03
2015-04-04
Week 2:
2015-04-05
2015-04-06
2015-04-07
2015-04-08
2015-04-09
```

In either case, you could map each of dates into a `Map` keyed by the week, but that's up to you

Answer (score 14):

If Java 8 were available:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
TemporalField weekOfYear = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).weekOfYear();

Stream.of(
      "04/01/2015"
    , "04/02/2015"
    , "04/03/2015"
    , "04/04/2015"
    , "04/05/2015"
    , "04/06/2015"
    , "04/07/2015"
    , "04/08/2015"
    , "04/09/2015"
)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    d -> LocalDate.parse(d, formatter).get(weekOfYear),
    LinkedHashMap::new,
    Collectors.toList()
))
.forEach((week, dates) -> {
    System.out.println("Week " + week + ":");

    dates.forEach(System.out::println);
});
```

This prints (using `de_CH` locale on my computer)

```
Week 14:
04/01/2015
04/02/2015
04/03/2015
04/04/2015
04/05/2015
Week 15:
04/06/2015
04/07/2015
04/08/2015
04/09/2015
```

Comment: Dang that some sweet code although I'm stuck in 7 :(

Comment: @stackoverflow: I thought so. But I'll leave the answer here for future visitors...

Comment: Is it just me, or is the output wrong?  Doesn't 01/04 drop in the same week as 02/04?

Comment: Yes, looks like wrong results if using [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). Week # 14 of 2015 runs from March 30 through April 5. That [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR) apparently counts weeks from the first date of the year rather than following the ISO week standard.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Huh true, it hadn't even occurred to me. That seems pretty useless as a property!

Comment: @LukasEder I still the like the concept and demonstration of the streams ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Fixed. My `java.time` is still a bit rusty

Comment: @maraca: No need to re-format the dates. The current version of the collector configuration doesn't modify the input strings. The lambda arg list `(week, dates)` is in fact `(int week, List<String> dates)`. It parses them just to get the week number. I referenced the locale because in some areas (e.g. `de_CH`), weeks start on Monday. In others they start on Sunday

Answer (score 4):

Use the power of functional programming with Java 8 Streams and use new Java Time Api:

Assuming that your dates are in a collection e.g:

```
List<LocalDate> dates = getMyDates();
 WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY,7);
 Map<Integer, List<LocalDate>> datesGroupedByWeekNumber  = dates.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(date -> date.get(weekFields.weekOfYear())));
```

You are going to get a Map where the key integer is the week number in the year and the value for that key is a List of dates where those dates belongs to that weekNumber.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get week number:

```
public static int getWeek(Date date) {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(date);
  return cal.get(WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

Comment: This would work but I need a returned 'Date' object unfortunately. cal.get(WEEK_OF_YEAR) only returns an integer of 1-52 i believe

Comment: That's right. So all dates with the same year and weekNo will fall int the same group, right? This is an algorithm to your program.

Comment: The problem with it is that you will have to add year * 52 or something, this only works in the same year.

Comment: That was an idea to start with. I have expended it in this [DEMO](http://ideone.com/uw5Caa)

Answer (score 1):

The for can't work the way you implemented it, here are some corrections:

```
for (Date i : dateArray) {
  Date date = getWhichYearlyWeek(date);
  if(treeMap.containsKey(date))
    treeMap.get(date).add(i);
  else {
    ArrayList<Date> al = new ArrayList<Date>();
    al.add(i);
    treeMap.put(date, al);
  }
}
```

1. If had a not but it shouldn't
2. You added the week instead of the date
3. You forgot to add the date to the empty ArrayList

Use `GregorianCalendar`:

```
public Date getWhichYearlyWeek(Date date) {
  GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
  cal.setTime(date);
  // (*) = remove if you are only dealing with real dates and not dateTime
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // (*)
  cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE); // (*)
  cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND); // (*)
  cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND); // (*)
  cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek()); // or Calendar.MONDAY
  return cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Like several others in other answers I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. The code below features:

- The list of dates in each week preserves the order the dates were in the original list,
- It handles different years
- Week scheme is specified so you can specify whether the week should be considered starting on Sunday or Monday, for example.

I am first declaring:

```
private static Locale weekLocale = Locale.FRANCE;
private static DateTimeFormatter weekFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Year' Y 'week' w", weekLocale);
private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter 
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Now the work goes like this:

```
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(weekLocale);
    
    List<LocalDate> dates = List.of(
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 1),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 2),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 3),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 4),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 5),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 6),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 7),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 8),
            LocalDate.of(2015, Month.APRIL, 9),
            LocalDate.of(2014, Month.APRIL, 9),
            LocalDate.of(2014, Month.APRIL, 6),
            LocalDate.of(2014, Month.APRIL, 1));
    
    // Group the dates by the first day of the week they are in
    Map<LocalDate, List<LocalDate>> datesByWeek = dates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1)));
    
    // Print results ordered by week
    datesByWeek.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .forEach(e -> {
                System.out.println(e.getKey().format(weekFormatter));
                e.getValue().forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.format(dateFormatter)));
                System.out.println();
            });
```

Output is:

> ```
> Year 2014 week 14
> Apr 6, 2014
> Apr 1, 2014
>
> Year 2014 week 15
> Apr 9, 2014
>
> Year 2015 week 14
> Apr 1, 2015
> Apr 2, 2015
> Apr 3, 2015
> Apr 4, 2015
> Apr 5, 2015
>
> Year 2015 week 15
> Apr 6, 2015
> Apr 7, 2015
> Apr 8, 2015
> Apr 9, 2015
> ```

If you wanted, say, American week numbers, change the declaration:

```
private static Locale weekLocale = Locale.US;
```

Output changes accordingly:

> ```
> Year 2014 week 14
> Apr 1, 2014
>
> Year 2014 week 15
> Apr 9, 2014
> Apr 6, 2014
>
> Year 2015 week 14
> Apr 1, 2015
> Apr 2, 2015
> Apr 3, 2015
> Apr 4, 2015
>
> Year 2015 week 15
> Apr 5, 2015
> Apr 6, 2015
> Apr 7, 2015
> Apr 8, 2015
> Apr 9, 2015
> ```

Apr 6, 2014 and Apr 5, 2015 are now in week 15 of their respective years because they are Sundays and US weeks begin on Sundays.

If you always want ISO weeks, you can write a yet more elegant solution by grouping by `YearWeek`, the class from the ThreeTen Extra project. Link: [`YearWeek` documentation](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you need to return date, try using `Calendar#clear()` and then `Calendar#setTime(Date)` and then use Calendar#get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR).

Since `#getWhichYearlyWeek(Date)` is now redundant you can possibly skip it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to group dates by WEEK_OF_YEAR.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GroupByWeekSampleCode {

    /**
     * @param year
     * @param weekOfYear
     * @return a unique hashcode generated from year and week of year
     */
    public static int getYearWeekOfYearHashCode(int year, int weekOfYear) {
        int result = (int) (((float) year + ((float) weekOfYear / 100)) * 100);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @param hashCode
     * @return the week of year from this hash code
     */
    public static int getWeekOfYearFromHashCode(int hashCode) {
        int year = (int) hashCode / 100;
        int weekOfYear = (int) (hashCode % year);
        return weekOfYear;
    }

    /**
     * @param hashCode
     * @return year from this hash code
     */
    public static int getYearFromHashCode(int hashCode) {
        int year = (int) hashCode / 100;
        return year;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            List<Date> datesToGroup = new ArrayList<Date>();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/01/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/02/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/03/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/04/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/05/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/06/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/07/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/08/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("04/09/2015"));

            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("12/27/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("12/28/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("12/29/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("12/30/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("12/31/2015"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("01/01/2016"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("01/02/2016"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("01/03/2016"));
            datesToGroup.add(sdf.parse("01/04/2016"));

            final Map<Integer, List<Date>> groupedDatesByWeekOfYear = new HashMap<Integer, List<Date>>() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public List<Date> get(Object key) {
                    List<Date> list = super.get(key);
                    if (list == null) {
                        list = new ArrayList<Date>();
                        super.put((Integer) key, list);
                    }
                    return list;
                }
            };

            for (Date date : datesToGroup) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(date);

                Calendar previousYearLastDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                previousYearLastDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1);
                previousYearLastDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
                previousYearLastDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                        previousYearLastDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                // a hash code generated from year and week of year value
                int yearWeekOfYearHashCode = 0;

                // to check if some of the dates in this week of year comes
                // in previous year last month, if true then the previous year
                // should be taken to generate hash code
                if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 0
                        && cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == previousYearLastDate.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)) {
                    yearWeekOfYearHashCode = getYearWeekOfYearHashCode(previousYearLastDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            previousYearLastDate.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
                } else {
                    yearWeekOfYearHashCode = getYearWeekOfYearHashCode(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
                }

                groupedDatesByWeekOfYear.get(yearWeekOfYearHashCode).add(date);
            }

            for (Integer yearWeekOfYearHashCode : groupedDatesByWeekOfYear.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("year=" + getYearFromHashCode(yearWeekOfYearHashCode) + ", weekOfYear="
                        + getWeekOfYearFromHashCode(yearWeekOfYearHashCode) + ", dates under this week ");

                List<Date> datesInThisWeek = groupedDatesByWeekOfYear.get(yearWeekOfYearHashCode);
                for (Date date : datesInThisWeek) {
                    System.out.println(date);
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(date);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print

```
year=2015, weekOfYear=1, dates under this week 
Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 IST 2015
Mon Dec 28 00:00:00 IST 2015
Tue Dec 29 00:00:00 IST 2015
Wed Dec 30 00:00:00 IST 2015
Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 2015
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2016
Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 IST 2016

year=2015, weekOfYear=14, dates under this week 
Wed Apr 01 00:00:00 IST 2015
Thu Apr 02 00:00:00 IST 2015
Fri Apr 03 00:00:00 IST 2015
Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 IST 2015

year=2015, weekOfYear=15, dates under this week 
Sun Apr 05 00:00:00 IST 2015
Mon Apr 06 00:00:00 IST 2015
Tue Apr 07 00:00:00 IST 2015
Wed Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 2015
Thu Apr 09 00:00:00 IST 2015

year=2016, weekOfYear=2, dates under this week 
Sun Jan 03 00:00:00 IST 2016
Mon Jan 04 00:00:00 IST 2016
```