# Grouping items by date

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-time

I have items in my list and the items have a field, which shows the creation date of the item.

[image]

and I need to group them based on a "compression", which the user gives. The options are `Day`, `Week`, `Month` and `Year`.

If the user selects `day` compression, I need to group my items as such that the items, which are created in the same day, will be groupped. In my example above, only item 1 and item 2 are created in the same day. The others are also groups but they will have only one item because at their day, only one item is created.

```
{{item1, item2}, {item3}, {item4}, {item5}, {item6}, {item7}}
```

If the user selects `week`:

```
{{item1, item2, item3, item4}, {item5}, {item6}, {item7}}
```

If the user selects `month`:

```
{{item1, item2, item3, item4, item5}, {item6}, {item7}}
```

If the user selects `year`:

```
{{item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6}, {item7}}
```

After groups are created, the date of the items are not important. I mean the key can be anything, as long as the groups are created.

In case of usage of `Map`, I thought as the keys as follow:

`day` = day of the year
`week` = week of the year
`month` = month of the year
`year` = year

What would be the best solution to this problem? I could not even start it an I cannot think of a solution other than iteration.

Comment: Why don't you upload all the data into a sql database and then you can take advantage of the "GROUP BY" sql function?

Comment: @rabbitguy I am working with a legacy code and can change only this part, not more.

Comment: @drJava which part exactly? you didn't post any effort

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Maybe, I am thinking too much but since 4 hours, I have thought of a solution and besides implementatin, I could not even start with a design.

Comment: @drJava I would do the proactive grouping - which means only one iteration that will create all needed groups as soon as the whole data is available (not at the request time). You can also create a customize data structure to keep both item data and key that will help in a search.

Comment: I think this solution is pretty neat. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954280/11428614

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would use `Collectors.groupingBy` with an adjusted `LocalDate` on the classifier, so that items with similar dates (according to the *compression* given by the user) are grouped together.

For this, first create the following `Map`:

```
static final Map<String, TemporalAdjuster> ADJUSTERS = new HashMap<>();

ADJUSTERS.put("day", TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster(d -> d)); // identity
ADJUSTERS.put("week", TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.of(1)));
ADJUSTERS.put("month", TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth());
ADJUSTERS.put("year", TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear());
```

Note: for `"day"`, a `TemporalAdjuster` that lets the date untouched is being used.

Next, use the `compression` given by the user to dynamically select how to group your list of items:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Item>> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getCreationDate()
            .with(ADJUSTERS.get(compression))));
```

The `LocalDate` is adjusted by means of the [`LocalDate.with(TemporalAdjuster)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) method.

Comment: thats actually very neat

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner good jobs. I just know that there is another tag [tag:java-stream] but it is  invisible in tag [tag:java-8] sometimes, so I can't see it in [tag:java-8], :(

Comment: what if i want to do something with the item before add it to the map?

Comment: @ThanosM you could use `Stream.map` in that case, before `Stream.collect`

Comment: Great answer, what if I want to group by n amount of months or days? Let's say group by 3 months

Comment: @Manos [Here's a way](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/first-day-of-quarter-java8-adjuster/) to do it. That's by quarter, but you get the idea to adapt it

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Exactly what I need thanks

Comment: This is awesome thanks for this great solution

Answer (score 8):

You can get the behaviour you describe with java 8 streams:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Data>> byYear = data.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(d -> d.getDate().withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(1)));
Map<LocalDate, List<Data>> byMonth = data.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(d -> d.getDate().withDayOfMonth(1)));
Map<LocalDate, List<Data>> byWeek = data.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(d -> d.getDate().with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))));
Map<LocalDate, List<Data>> byDay = data.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(d -> d.getDate()));
```

Docs for [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-). In all 4 cases [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is used as key. To group appropriately, it is modified so that all dates have the same month and day or same day but different month or same month and same day of week (Monday) which leads to obvious grouping rules. The date in your data is not modified only the key. This will consider that the month is the same when also the year is the same and the day is the same when the full date is the same.

For example when grouping by month these dates will have the same key:

> 01/01/2017 --> key 01/01/2017
>   04/01/2017 --> key 01/01/2017
>   05/01/2017 --> key 01/01/2017

and when grouping by week these dates will have the same key (date is previous monday):

> 04/01/2017 --> key 02/01/2017
>   05/01/2017 --> key 02/01/2017

You may want instead to group by same day of month for example regardless of year and month. You would achieve it like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Data>> byDayOfMonth = data.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(d -> d.getDate().getDayOfMonth()));
```

Which would group together 01/01/2017 with 01/10/2017 and then 05/01/2017 with 05/04/2018

Comment: I have added some examples of dates. I hope it's clearer now. When grouping by day the full date is used. If grouping by new dates created with the 1st day of the month just as keys. The original dates remain the same

Comment: You mentioned in previous comment that you have the old `Date` instead of the new and shiny `LocalDate` in Java 8. Given the lack of convenient methods like `withDayOfMonth` for `Date` I'd recommend transforming `Date` to `LocalDate` for generating keys. E.g. `new java.sql.Date(d.getDate().getTime()).toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1)`

Comment: Yes, I have the old date and then, I have converted them to localDate. Because of this reason, I have removed my comment :) Thank you for added info.

Answer (score 4):

The only detail I'd pay more attention is the week definition. I'm assuming that your week starts at Sunday and if it must have at least a minimum of 1 day to be considered the first week. (ISO 8601 states that a week starts at Monday and it must have at least 4 days to be considered the first week - if it has fewer days, it's considered week zero). You can check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) for more details about week definitions.

To get this week definition, I'm using `java.time.temporal.WeekFields` class. I'm using the `of` method that explicits uses the first day of week and the minimum number of days in the first week (if I use the version that takes a `Locale`, results might differ depending on the system's default locale).

I also created an enum for the compression type, but that's optional:

```
enum CompressionType {
    DAY, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR;
}
```

Anyway, I use the compression type to know which field will be used to group the dates. Then I used `Collectors.groupingBy` to do the grouping:

```
// assuming you have a list of dates
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 4));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 5));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 29));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 10, 1));
dates.add(LocalDate.of(2018, 4, 5));

CompressionType compression = // get CompressionType from user input
final TemporalField groupField;
switch (compression) {
    case DAY:
        groupField = ChronoField.DAY_OF_YEAR;
        break;
    case WEEK:
    // week starts at Sunday, minimum of 1 day in the first week
        groupField = WeekFields.of(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, 1).weekOfWeekBasedYear();
        break;
    case MONTH:
        groupField = ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR;
        break;
    case YEAR:
        groupField = ChronoField.YEAR;
        break;
    default:
        groupField = null;
}
if (groupField != null) {
    Map<Integer, List<LocalDate>> result = dates.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.get(groupField)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your item element have these attributes :

```
private String item;
private LocalDate date;
```

You can do like this :

```
ArrayList<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Element("item 1", LocalDate.of(2017, 01, 01)));
list.add(new Element("item 2", LocalDate.of(2017, 01, 01)));

WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
String userChoice = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
Map<Integer, List<Element>> map;

switch (userChoice) {
     case "day":
          map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element 
                              -> element.getDate().getDayOfMonth()));
          break;
     case "week":
          map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element 
                              -> element.getDate().get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear())));
          break;
     case "month":
          map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element 
                              -> element.getDate().getMonthValue()));
          break;
     case "year":
          map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element 
                              -> element.getDate().getYear()));
          break;
     default:
          break;
}
```

Depending on the user choice, the map would result as mapping the items following his choice

---

**Details :**

```
map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(element 
                                        -> element.getDate().getYear()));
```

This will iterate over the item of the list, and look at the `year of the date of the item` to group them by it

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashMap like this

```
 <Integer,ArrayList<Date>>

1. set filter=DAY/MONTH/YEAR

2.Iterate the date_obj

3.Use Calendar package to get a variable val=Calendar.get(filter)

4. If hashmap.keyset().contains(val)
      hashmap.get(val).add(date_obj.date)
   Else
      hashmap.put(val,new ArrayList<date_obj>());
```