# How to group items by fiscal year with Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a list of monthly store sales such that:

```
ID, date, amount
1, Jan 2016, $500
2, Feb 2017, $200
3, October 2017, $300
```

And my fiscal year is Sept 1, 2016 to August 31, 2017. In other words the first two entries are in one fiscal year and the other in the second fiscal year. The actual fiscal year is user specific.

I want to create a list of `storeSales` for each fiscal year.

So far I have:

```
Map<fiscalYearID, List<StoreSale> = storeSales.stream()
                                .collect(
                                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                                        storeSale -> storeSale.getSaleLocalDate()));
```

The problem is that the above code will only group by exact date. I could add `.getYear()` but [that would only group by year and NOT fiscal year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060886/grouping-items-by-date). I also thought about using `Stream.iterate()` for each fiscal year date range and then going through the list of store sales for all stores that are within that date range into a list but that gets pretty ugly and the big O value starts to quickly climb. That would be something like:

```
Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusMonths(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startDate, endDate.plusMonths(1)))
        .forEach(
        {
            addToFiscalYear(fiscalYearID, 
                    storeSales.stream().
                            .filter(storeSale -> storeSale.getSaleLocalDate().equals(date))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
```

Or something like that. I didn't explore it too much because the big O of that quickly increases and I'm hoping there is a better solution...

Comment: May the fiscal year begin on any date of the year (save Feb 29), or does it always begin on the first of a month?

Comment: What is the type returned by `getSaleLocalDate()`? (It seems `YearMonth` would be appropriate, but the name rather suggests `LocalDate`.)

Comment: I left it open so that it could be whatever was most convenient ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a method that accepts a date and returns a fiscalYearID:

```
public static fiscalYearID getFiscalYearID (Date date)
{
    // return fiscal year ID matching passed date
}
```

Now you can group by `fiscalYearID` (assuming `fiscalYearID` is a class that overrides `equals`):

```
Map<fiscalYearID, List<StoreSale>> = 
    storeSales.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> getFiscalYearID (s.getSaleLocalDate())));
```

Comment: That's one method but it's still a large big O value if I do that. Not to mention implementing that method is not simple...

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Why isn't it simple to implement that method? Obtain the month from the date, if it's >= Sept, return the next year, else return the current year.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier And what do you mean by large big O value? It should be linear time (the input list is traversed exactly once).

Comment: @Eran not to mention that I would expect you need a method like that in code like that anyway. A `FiscalYear` constructor with it, actually.

Comment: @daniu I agree.

Comment: I don’t think, `date` is a `Date`, as everything in the question looks like the `java.time` API. So it’s likely a `Temporal` or `LocalDate`…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I just made an arbitrary decision here, since it wasn't specified, and it doesn't really affect the answer. I'm also not sure there's an actual fiscalYearID type (the actual type might be a String or an int).

Comment: Assuming `LocalDate` it shouldn’t be hard to implement the method. If the date is before the beginning of the fiscal year (compare `MonthDay` objects), it belongs to the fiscal year starting the year before, else the fiscal year that continues into next year. Only there’s a special case if the fiscal year happens to coincide with the calendar year.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something you could do:

Since the fiscal year is determined by the user, you can calculate the offset of the fiscal year. For example, if the fiscal year starts at September, the offset would be 9 months. You can `map` the fiscal years to normal years by subtracting 9 months. This should be easy with the Java 8 date API. Then, you can use your usual `groupingBy(storeSale -> storeSale.getSaleLocalDate().getYear())` to group the dates.