# Group stream of elements by day, week or year

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I'm trying to find a way to group a stream of elements by day, week or year.

I have this entity:

```
element {
 id 
 date(ZonedDateTime)
}
```

So maybe I can do something like that:

```
elemets.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getDate().with(TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster('group by day, week or month')));
```

Is this possible?

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean day, week *or* year? care to provide an example?

Comment: @Eugene  elements with the same day,  same week ... so is grouping by their owns dates by day, week or month

Comment: this is still unclear, so you want to group first by day, then by week and so on? so for example `Monday = [Some entries where monday is the day]`, `32 = [some entries that are on week 32]`?

Comment: Sorry @Eugene for not be clear, is just groping by day || week || month

Comment: I understood that, but I still don't understand how that grouping is suppose to work. that is why I said provide a small example of what *exactly* you mean

Comment: Ok, element.getDate().getDay()--> group all elements with this day

Comment: ... and where is week or year?

Comment: Maybe it should be a parametrized function like `group(Collection<MyElement> elements, ChronoUnit cu, long value)`?

Comment: @Eugene :)  week or year will be another grouping by,  not at the same time.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060886/grouping-items-by-date/45068322#45068322)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely sure this is what you need, but seems like a method that takes the value you want to group by is what you are after:

```
private static Map<Integer, List<Element>> group(
        Collection<Element> elements, 
        ChronoField chronoField) {
    return elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 x -> x.getDateTime().get(chronoField)));
}
```

And for example calling it via:

```
group(elements, ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK);
group(elements, ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR);
group(elements, ChronoField.YEAR);
```

Comment: I'll check Eugene, thanks for your time.